# why object of inner class cannot be generated in generics

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

I have a following code

```
class OuterClass<T>{

class Innerclass{
int k;
}

public static void main(String argv[]){

OuterClass<Integer> out =new OuterClass<>();
Innerclass in; // errors out
}

}
```

But for a class with no generics like the following code, I could create object for inner class.

```
class OuterClass{

class Innerclass{
int k;
}

public static void main(String argv[]){

OuterClass out =new OuterClass();
Innerclass in; // No error

}

}
```

why am i not able to create object of inner class though no generics are used in the inner class in my first example? Please explain.

Comment: Note that neither version of the code actually creates an instance of the inner class. You only declare a variable of the inner class's type.

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method belongs to `OuterClass` and is static in there. Since `InnerClass` is not a static class but implicitly depends on the generic type `T` (the generic type is available in the inner class, even if your example isn't using it), you cannot reference it from a static method.

In other words, since `InnerClass` depends on the generic type, you cannot break it "lose" from `OuterClass` and use it outside of it.

If your inner class won't depend on the generic type, you can just make it static. However, you might want to consider just extracting it into a separate class rather than nesting classes in this case:

```
class OuterClass<T> {
    static class InnerClass {
        int k;
    }

    public static void main( String argv[] ) {
        InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

If the generic is important for the inner class, you can tell the compiler which generic to infer for the outer class by specifying it (note that the generic type of `outer` and `inner` must match) or by using `OuterClass.InnerClass` in which case the compiler will use the raw type:

```
class OuterClass<T> {
    class InnerClass {
        int k;
    }

    public static void main( String argv[] ) {
        OuterClass<String> outer = new OuterClass<String>();

        // works and has the "correct" generic type
        OuterClass<String>.InnerClass inner1 = outer.new InnerClass();

        // works, but uses the raw type
        OuterClass.InnerClass inner2 = outer.new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

Note that you need an enclosing instance `outer` of type `OuterClass<T>` in order to instantiate `InnerClass` (since the class is not static, it belongs to an instance of `OuterClass`).

This also goes for the example without generics: you will need an enclosing instance to instantiate the inner class, so

```
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
        int k;
    }

    public static void main( String argv[] ) {
        OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
        InnerClass in = outer.new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

will work while

```
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
        int k;
    }

    public static void main( String argv[] ) {
        OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
        InnerClass in = new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

won't.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the version without generics compiles.

Comment: @user2357112 It only compiles because he is not instanciating the class. A mere `InnerClass in = new InnerClass()` will fail even in the version without generics as no enclosing instance is given. I edited my answer.

Comment: The new version of the answer explains more. I'd like to add that `OuterClass.InnerClass inner;` compiles whether or not `OuterClass` is generic, since it uses the raw type. `InnerClass inner;` attempts to use the parameterized type and has no type parameter to supply.